# Is it possible to use azure service bus with python securely?

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

There's good amount of documentation on how to set security options for using azure service bus within .NET. I could not find any documentations or options for using it with encrypted messaging with Python. 
Is it possible to use Azure Service Bus securely (encrypted messages)?

Answer (score 1):

May I know what particular encryption you are seeking for? Per my experience, Service Bus always adopts TLS/SSL, so the transport layer is already encrypted. If you want to encrypt the messages, then please note neither .NET nor Python Azure SDK performs message level encryption for brokered messages. If you're using the old relayed message, which was used to bypass local NAT, and IMHO it’s rarely used today since we have virtual network, then there is message level security built in. But relayed messages rely on WCF, which is only available for .NET, and they don't provide features such as queues, topics, and subscriptions. I think you're using brokered message, if I am right, in this case, it’s needed to encrypt messages manually. Please refer to [Encryption with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130687/encryption-with-python) on how to encrypt data in Python. Please make sure all senders and receivers know how to encrypt/decrypt. If you're looking for other security options, such as authentication, I’d like to suggest you to check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn155925.aspx. The authentication settings are platform natural. The same setting works for both .NET and Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I am looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt brokered messages. Some clients will be in .Net and some in Python. Looks like I need to find an encryption solution that i can use both in .Net and python and encrypt messages before sending and decrypt when I receive them. Do you have a recommendation for an encryption method for this scenario?

Comment: Hello derdo, as mentioned previously the data is not encrypted out of box, however the communications are encrypted. If you want to encrypt the data, it's needed to find an encryption algorithm that works in both .NET and Python. This is actually not specific to Service Bus, e.g. you can take the same approach to encrypt data in, say, a database. On the Python side, please find a library, such as Python Cryptography Toolkit (https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/).

Comment: On the .NET side, there're several built-in encryption algorithms. You can refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10154/NET-Encryption-Simplified for a sample. Since most algorithms are open standards, as long as you choose the same algorithm on both .NET and Python, it should work fine. In addition, please make sure to securely manage the encryption keys.